# Use scp to transfer a file from local directory X to remote directory Y

Tags: scp

I took a look around at other questions here and at various "scp usage" tutorials on Internet, but I can't sort out what's wrong.

I'm using Linux Mint and I'm trying to figure out how **scp** works.

I've a file **file.ext** (on my computer) in directory **/home/name/dir/**

I connect to a remote machine using **ssh**, like:

```
ssh -p 2222 username@domain
```

it asks me the password and the shell displays:

```
username@domain ~ $
```

now, If I issue the command (before I ran ssh I was in the local directory  **/home/name/dir** ):

```
scp -r -P 2222 file.ext username@domain
```

output is:

```
cp: cannot stat ‘file.ext’: No such file or directory
```

Same result if instead of file.ext I write the complete path

```
scp -r -P 2222 /home/name/dir/file.ext username@domain
```

Also, the server admin told me that I shall upload the file to my remote home directory (instead of root), like:

```
scp -r -P 2222 file.ext username@domain:~/
```

but when I do it and press "Enter" nothing happens, as If the shell was waiting for further input.

Summary of my problems:

- cp: no such file or directory
- shell "stuck" on ~/

Any suggestions?

Comment: it's slightly unclear whether your problem is only related to being on the wrong machine...could you please prefix each command with the host you are running on? e.g. `localuser@machineA: ssh -p 2222 username@domain` (to indicate that you are running the ssh command as localuser on machineA)

Comment: when using `scp`, the *remote* side always has to contain the colon (e.g. `remotehost:/tmp`), else it will just do an ordinary copy (`scp /tmp/foo.txt example.com` will copy `/tmp/foo.txt` into a local file `example.com`)

Comment: remove the `-r` flag, as this is not needed for copying single files (it's used to *recursively* copy directories)

Comment: Are you issuing the scp command *inside the sshe session*? It would make sense if you are on the local machine.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You need to run the `scp` command from the local machine, not on the remote. You don't need the `ssh` at all:

```
dragonmnl@local $ scp -P 2222 file.ext username@domain:~/
```

You also don't need the `-r`:

```
 -r      Recursively copy entire directories.
```

If you are already logged into the remote machine and want to copy from your local, you need to make sure that your local machine is accessible via the internet and has `ssh` set up. I don't think this is what you are after but if it is, just run this from the remote:

```
username@domain $ scp dragonmnl@local:/path/to/file.ext ~/
```

Comment: thanks. the problem was I was trying running scp inside ssh session. now it works!

Answer (score 43):

I provide two methods of up/down load file between remote and local machine(I use Mac air):

In this case, I want to up/down `11.jpeg` between local and remote:

1. > **Copy files on service to local dir: You must be in local bash terminal to conduct this command, not when you are in ssh!**

   ```
   scp username@domain:/home/xxx/xxx/11.jpeg /Users/username/Desktop/
   ```

   > **copy files in local dir to remote service : also you must be in local bash terminal**

   ```
   scp /Users/username/Desktop/11.jpeg username@domain:/home/xxx/xxx
   ```
2. To achieve the same intention **when you are logging in the SSH**, you must first set “System Preferences>sharing>remote log in>all users(I am not sure if you must set for "all users", but it works in this situation)” the Mac will tell you"To log in to this computer remotely, type:

   ```
   ssh username@xxxxxx, then type in the command below:
   scp username@domain:/home/xxx/xxx/11.jpeg username@xxxxxx:/Users/username/Desktop/**
   ```

This command above is for downloading file from remote to local when you are logging into ssh, Just change the two path when you want to upload file .

Comment: Finally, I find Filezilla is probably the most convenient one in daily work~~

Answer (score 17):

### Update

We can also use `scp -r source_folder destination_folder` if not too many files in the folder.

### Original Answer

#### Use the `scp` command

If you want to transfer a folder, just `zip` it first, we can `unzip` it later on.

From your computer, run this:

```
$ scp your_path_to_the_file/the_file root@10.145.198.100:~/
```

Here, `root` is your account, and `10.145.198.100` is the remote server's IP address. We're going to copy `the_file` to `~/` folder in the remote.

#### Unzip file:

```
$ unzip the_zip_file.zip -d destination_folder
```

Comment: Why would `root` even have SSH access on the remote machine?  That's pretty insecure. Better to use an ordinary use and then `sudo` to do whatever root has to do on that machine.

Comment: You don't need "~/" just "scp your_path_to_the_file/the_file root@10.145.198.100:" will default to home

Answer (score 6):

If you're running this scp command on the remote machine, it is looking for `file.ext` as a "local" file, i.e. **on the remote machine.**

To copy a file from the remote machine to the local one, use `scp -P 2222 username@domain:dir/file.ext localdir` (assuming that `file.ext` is in `~/dir` on the remote computer, as in your example). If you run `scp` on the remote machine, reverse "local" and "remote".

Comment: The OP _wants_ to copy from local to remote, see the OP's title.

Comment: Oops, I guess you're right. But he's apparently doing it backwards...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to copy files from Linux client to Linux server**

1. Check if `sshd` is running on your server using:
   `ps aux | grep sshd`
2. If not, install `OpenSSH` using
   `sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client`
   https://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-in-linux/
3. Restart your server and verify that `sshd` is running using
   `ps aux | grep sshd`
4. If you need you can configure your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file,
   but it's not
   necessary for simple configurations
5. verify that the ports are open using `netcat`: 
   `nc -v -z 127.0.0.1 22`
6. To copy files from a `Linux` client to a `Linux` client use scp as follows
   `scp ~/filename.md username@10.22.33.45:~/folder/filename.md`
7. To verify that file has been copied use
   `ssh username@10.22.33.45` and provide your password.

**Solution to copy files from Linux client to Windows**

1. There are multiple clients for running SSH servers on Windows,  such as:

   - [OpenSSH from MS](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH)
   - [MobaSSH](https://mobassh.mobatek.net/)
   - [Bitvise SSH server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server-download)
2. Install one of the above servers and make sure that port 22 is open using

   ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SSH Port 22" dir=in action=allow protocol=UDP localport=22
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SSH Port 22" dir=out action=allow protocol=UDP localport=22
   ```

   ```
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SSH Port 22" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=22
   netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SSH Port 22" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=22
   ```

   ```
   netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
   ```
3. Comparisons of these servers:

   Bitvise SSH server

   1. Provides almost close to native `cmd` prompt, `powershell` prompt,
      autocompletion
   2. Provides additional capabilities for customization, if you need
      advanced usage
   3. User customization for simple needs is 0. I got started on it within
      2 minsute, after having spent a lot of time trying to get `MobaSSH` and
      `OpenSSH` to work.
   4. To copy files using scp use:
      `scp ~/filename.md username@10.33.44.45:/C/Users/username/filename.md`
   5. Free for personal use, $99 for professional use. Because of so many
      features and great integration, the price is well worth the money.

   MobaSSH:

   1. provides a Linux shell on Windows where simple Linux commands such
      as `ls`, `cp`, `find`, etc., work, similar to `MINGW64`
   2. you can access `cmd` and `powershell` directly by typing `cmd` or
      `powershell`
   3. Unicode support is poor. Encoding is not correct. For example if you
      try to start `Python` interpretor, it will crash. You will need to
      change the encoding manually using
      (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12834315/4752883):
      `chcp 65001`
      `set PYTHONIOENCONDING=utf-8`
      and then startup Python prompt
   4. The great thing about MobaSSH is that it has a very simple
      user-interface, and `scp` and `ssh` and integrated well. So will
      work for simple use cases
   5. To copy files from a Linux client to a Windows server running
      `MobaSSH`: use
      `scp ~/filename.md username@10.33.44.45:/cygdrive/c/Users/username/filename.md`
      This is because `MobaSSH` is based on Cygwin and its drives are
      mapped to the same way `cygwin`-s drives are mapped.

   Use VMs from Microsoft with OpenSSHv6.7 installed from
   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/,
   OpenSSHv6.7 is already installed.

   1. It's very buggy, and you will need to heavily customize it.
   2. Command completion doesn't work
   3. It will leave blank spaces when you are moving cursor on the terminal
   4. Python doesn't work
   5. Later versions of OpenSSH, may have improved on it. Further, MS seems to
      make OpenSSH available via "Optional Features"
      https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Answer (score 1):

Just a small contribution, maybe it can help beginners like me: the path to the the remote directory should be written like this: `username@domain:~/remote_directory`

What I want to highlight here is that we should always add that `:~/`

Answer (score -1):

#### If you happen to be on OSX...

When I tried running it with username@local:/file_directory...

I got the following error:

```
ssh: local: node name or service name not known
```

#### Solution

On my Mac I had to do the following to setup local `ssh`:

> ‘System Preferences’ --> ‘Internet & Networking’ --> ‘Sharing’ --> **ENABLE** ‘Remote Login’

This then provided the username@ip address.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem today on MAC.

Type the following command:

```
scp /local-file-path/ /-remote-location-path/
```