# How do I scp via ssh?

Tags: ssh, osx, ip, scp, remote

I have a LINUX machine (remote), and a MAC machine (local). Our system administrator set up an "SSH" method, whereby I can ssh from my MAC, to my LINUX machine, via this command on my MAC:

```
ssh marcus@gateway.highlabs.co -p 12345
```

When I do this, I am prompted to put in the password for my LINUX machine, and when I do, I have access, which is great.

What I want to do now though, is be able to scp from my MAC machine, to my LINUX machine, so that I can transfer files over. How do I do that? I have googled around but I am not sure what to do.

Thank you

Comment: Or rather of a question regarding the copying in the direction from the local machine to the remote one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115560/4319

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To copy from **REMOTE** to **LOCAL**:

```
scp -P 12345 user@server:/path/to/remote/file /path/to/local/file
```

To copy from **LOCAL** to **REMOTE**:

```
scp -P 12345 /path/to/local/file user@server:/path/to/remote/file
```

Note: The switch to specify port for `scp` is `-P` instead of `-p`

If you want to copy all files in a directory you can use wildcards like below:

```
scp -P 12345 user@server:/path/to/remote/dir/* /path/to/local/dir/
```

or even

```
scp -P 12345 user@server:/path/to/remote/dir/*.txt /path/to/local/dir/
```

Comment: What is "user@server" here though?

Comment: `user` = username .  `server` = hostname or IP address.  From your mac it would be `marcus@gateway.highlabs.co` but if you ssh into the linux machine and wanted to copy something back to your mac, you would need to use your mac username/hostname.

Comment: Hi Jesse, yes I guess what I dont understand is what the "server" should be since I do not know the IP of the remote...

Comment: if `gateway.highlabs.co` is the remote machine then `gateway.highlabs.co` is the hostname/FQDN...or at least is aliased/in your /etc/hosts.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean - I think this worked! I just had to put the -P 12345 right after the scp command though. :D One last q: How would I move a bunch of files altogether at the same time with one scp command? Thank you so much you saved my Saturday!! :D

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day. I was using lower case p for the port and struggling with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you are doing this frequently I would suggest adding some config in the file `~/.ssh/config`

add the following lines

```
Host highlabs
   Hostname gateway.highlabs.co
   User marcus
   Port 12345
```

Then you can

`ssh highlabs`

or

`scp highlabs:/path/to/file /local/path/to/file`

to copy from the server

or

`scp /local/path/to/file highlabs:/remote/path/to/file`

to copy to the server

If you are using key auth tab completion works the whole way, For example `ssh hi<tab>` will finish off the word and `scp highlabs:/et<tab>`  will expand to /etc after checking the files on the remote server

Comment: Hi @exussum that is really helpful—but the tab completion does not work on my Mac OSX (10.14.5) using Z-shell. Any ideas how to change that? I would love the TAB competition for remote filepaths to work.

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203931/whats-the-magic-that-allows-me-to-tab-complete-remote-files-as-i-type-an-scp-co

Answer (score 5):

You should use something like this

```
scp -P 12345 -p some_file marcus@gateway.highlabs.co:
```

This will copy `some_file` to your home directory on the remote server. Change the name or path by putting the alternative immediately after the `:` (no space). Swap the arguments to copy back to the local system.

The `-P 12345` is equivalent to your `-p 12345` and the `-p` flag tells `scp` to maintain the timestamps and permissions for the destination file.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to reconcile what you wrote with that @Jesse_b wrote - I would like to copy a file from my mac to the remote, and vice-versa..

Comment: Ok I think I got it to work... however it keeps asking me for my password everytime I run the command - how do I make it so I just need to enter the password once? Thanks!!

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond the command uses the `ssh` transport to log you in each time you copy a file. Search (on the this site, amongst other places) for "password-less logins" and "ssh certificates".