# Methods to copy a file or a folder one linux server to another linux server

Tags: linux, file-copy

What is the most accurate way to copy a file or a folder from one linux machine to another using commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use scp to transfer a file from local directory X to remote directory Y](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115560/use-scp-to-transfer-a-file-from-local-directory-x-to-remote-directory-y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various options like `ftp`, `rsync` etc. but the most useful of these is the `scp` which comes preinstalled with `openssh` package. Syntax is simple:

```
scp file.txt user@host:/folder/to/which/user/has/permissions
```

There are some other flags, for example, if you are using a different port other than `22` for `ssh`, you'd need to mention that in the command with `-P` option.

```
scp -P PORT file.txt user@host:/folder/to/which/user/has/permissions
```

For directories, it is advised to archive folder(s) in some container. The most easy is one is `tar`:

```
tar -cvf myfolder.tar folder1 folder2 folderN
```

And then use `scp` to send it across to another Linux machine (just replace `file.txt` with `myfolder.tar`).

Answer (score 0):

`rsync -a` should be as accurate as accuracy can get. 
`-a` stands for the archive mode. 
A good description is given in [its `man` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html):

>   ```
>   rsync -avz foo:src/bar /data/tmp
>   ```
>
> This would recursively transfer all files from the directory src/bar on
>          the  machine foo into the /data/tmp/bar directory on the local machine. 
>          The files are transferred in "archive" mode, which  ensures  that
>          symbolic  links,  devices,  attributes,  permissions, ownerships, etc. are
>          preserved in the transfer.  Additionally, compression will be  used  to
>          reduce the size of data portions of the transfer.

The compression flag is `-z` and `-v` switches verbosity on. 
Study [the `man` page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html) to find out much more.